# Stylus mixins block

Tags: css, mixins, stylus

I have a list of class paired with colors, I would like to set different properties (`color`, `background`, `border-color`, ...) with the defined colors inside a mixin.

**Example**

```
colorHome = #FFF
colorParam = #999
colorDash = #000

links = {
  'home': colorHome,
  'param': colorParam,
  'dash': colorDash
}

.dashboard-menu li
  border 1px solid
  +addLinks()
    color clr
    background clr
    border-color clr
```

**would output to**

```
.dashboard-menu li {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.dashboard-menu li.home {
  color: #fff;
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
}
.dashboard-menu li.param {
  color: #999;
  background: #999;
  border-color: #999;
}
.dashboard-menu li.dash {
  color: #000;
  background: #000;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

**The mixin I have right now, using block.**

```
addLinks()
  for key, value in links
    clr = value
    &.{key}
      {block}


.dashboard-menu li
  border 1px solid
    +addLinks()
      color clr
      background clr
      border-color clr
```

But for some reason, `clr` is set to the first color (colorHome / #FFF) for `background`, and `border-color`, and set to the last color (colorDash / #000) for the `color`.

**Output**

```
.dashboard-menu li {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.dashboard-menu li.home {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
}
.dashboard-menu li.param {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
}
.dashboard-menu li.dash {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

Considering block mixins are relatively news, can they be used to achieve what I want ? Or should I consider using a completely different solution ?

Thanks

Comment: looks good for me. doesn't it work?

Comment: If you look at output, background and border-color are always the same (#FFF) when they should be #FFF for .home, #999 for .param and #000 for .dash. I have set the output I would like to (just after example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using a different solution. The contents you're passing to a block mixin is evaluated before the mixin's code, so it always would be the same from the run to run.

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve there, but here is one example of how you could do the thing you've tried:

```
addLinks(hash)
  for key, value in links
    new_hash = clone(hash)
    for hash_key, hash_value in new_hash
      if hash_value == clr
        new_hash[hash_key] = value

    &.{key}
      {new_hash}
      {block}

.dashboard-menu li
  border 1px solid
  addLinks({
    color: clr
    background: clr
    border-color: clr
  })
```

You can use non-block mixin for any properties you want to apply with the color from your `links` object, and if you'd need something else, you could use the block mixin notation altogether:

```
.dashboard-menu li
  border 1px solid
  +addLinks({
      color: clr
      background: clr
      border-color: clr
    })
    padding: 10px
```

We're thinking on adding a way to modify the passed block like a hash, but we're not here yet :)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to works. I would like to add function on these color : darken(clr, 10) for example. Is there any replace function in stylus ? Or at least a function to iterate character by char on a string ? (string[index] for example ?)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your comment. 1. You can use functions on the colors from the hash as usual: `new_hash[hash_key] = darken(value, 10)`, and there is a replace function (works only with idents or strings), undocummented yet. You can see the use case at tests: [before](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/1366361af0a1be55a8ff5324fd2c0de424c43462/test/cases/bifs.replace.styl) and [after](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/1366361af0a1be55a8ff5324fd2c0de424c43462/test/cases/bifs.replace.css).

Comment: When you plan to add a way to modify the passed block like a hash? This is a very usefull feature.

Comment: And can we parse `block` as hash?